# How to access Web.config which is located in another sub folder

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, web-config, connection-string

I have folder structure like this.

> \Root
>
> ```
>   \Sub1
>
>         \Sub2
> ```

Each having separate Web.config file.

**Is there any possible to access Web.config in the Sub1 from Root folder?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28049366/4207332).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap("~/Root/Sub1/Web.config"); //Path to your config file
    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
    string value = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["sKey"].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks.. @Mahendra Singh Dhami