# Make Angular routes use index.html base href attribute?

Tags: angular, iis, angular-routing

Is there any way to make the angular paths take the `base href` attribute of the `index.html` file after building the application, so that if I change the `base href` value the app makes the requests to another url without building the app again?

I know I can achieve this by adding `baseHref` to `angular.json`

```json
"architect": {
   "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
         "baseHref" : "/MyApp/"
      }
   }
}
```

But I'm trying to avoid rebuilding every time.

I also thought changing my iis site configuration, but I have multiple applications inside my site so updating the site config would break those:

- Site

  - Application 1
  - Application 2
  - MyApp

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Web server work (not Angular Router). I faced with the same problem with i18n. (Some usefull article for this case: https://medium.com/@feloy/deploying-an-i18n-angular-app-with-angular-cli-fc788f17e358)

1) I build two diferent application with: baseHref="/" and "baseHref": "/fr/".

2) Then config IIS web.config to switch betweeen thouse two application.

Hope its help!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that I have multiple applications inside my iis site, so if I change the site configuration the other apps would not work :(

Comment: May be its help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049253/understanding-web-config-hierarchy-in-subfolders (I belive you can config Web.config hierarchy for all sites separately)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following configuration:

```
"options": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "baseHref": "/MyApp/",
              "deployUrl": "/MyApp/"

            }
```